# Подскажите месяц и время должны меняться, когда я нажимаю любой селектор. Что не так

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, select

```
<div class="select">
    <form class="selectform">
        <label for="cars">Select Building</label>
        <select id="select">
            <option id="car1" value="Mers" >Mers</option>
            <option id="car2" value="2022-07" >Volvo</option>
            <option id="car3" value="Bmw">BMW</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

<form class="form" id="form">
    <div class="form-control">
        <label>Day</label>
        <input type="month" placeholder="day"  id="day" value="2022-06" >
    </div>

    <div class="form-control">
        <label>Time-From</label>
        <input type="time" placeholder="time from" value="" id="time">
    </div>

    <div class="form-control">
        <label>Time-To</label>
        <input type="time" placeholder="time to"  id="time2">
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
var date= new Date('December 25, 1995 23:15:30');
month = date.getMonth()
var select = document.getElementById('car2');
var day = document.getElementById('day');

select.addEventListener("click", changedMonth);
function changedMonth(){
    day.innerHTML=month;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас переменная month инициализируется лишь единожды, а должна инициализироваться в момент срабатывания слушателя.

```
select.addEventListener("click", changedMonth);
function changedMonth(){
    var date= new Date('December 25, 1995 23:15:30');
    month = date.getMonth()
    day.innerHTML=month;
}
```

Не очень понимаю при чем тут vuejs